# installing codeigniter framework on web server not working

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I have a project done using codeigniter framework, this project is working fine in localhost. But when i installed it on my web server the project is not working.

I am uploaded the files inside one folder named `online`

when am using following htaccess. am getting `500 internal server error`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /online/
RewriteCond $1   !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt|assets/js|assets/css|assets/img|assets/fonts|assets/uploads)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

But when am using the below htaccess. am able to load the `home` page, but other pages and images are not loading. It showing `page not found`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt|assets/js|assets/css|assets/img|assets/fonts|assets/uploads)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ online/index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

My `base_url` is,

```
$config['base_url'] = 'www.site.com/online/';
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

and my `default_controller is`

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'home';
```

and my file structure is,

```
-site_root (www.site.com)
 -online (folder)
  -application
  -assets
  -system
  -.htaccess
  -index.php
```

Why my site is not loading. What is the problem. I tried a lot. Is there any solution.

Comment: Put `http://www.example.com/online/` in config. Notice `PHP_URL_SCHEME`.

Answer (score 0):

**In `.htaccess`**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

**In base URL**

```
$config['base_url'] = 'www.site.com/';
```

**In routes**

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'home';
```

Comment: my CI files are inside `online` folder. Check the question again.

Comment: get outside of online folder